# Is it possible to name index that is created during primary key creation in oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing, primary-key

To my understanding, During primary key creation:

**a)** Oracle creates new index on prmary key field, if no index exists on the primary key field or its combination

**b)** Oracle uses one of the index on prmary key field, if more than one index exists on the primary key field or its combination but index is not specified

**c)** Oracle uses the index, if any index exists on the primary key field or its combination and index name is specified

**d)** Oracle uses one the index on primary key field, if only one index exists on the primary key field or its combination even index is not specified

Please suggest the possibility of setting name to the index created by oracle using the CREATE TABLE statement itself, in case (a)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the name of the index is the same as the name of the constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_tbl PRIMARY KEY);
```

Constraint naming is optional that's why both constraint and implicitly created index can get system generated name.

You can specify the index name using

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_tbl PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_pk_index ON tbl(ID)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example with name:

```
CREATE TABLE regions
   ( region_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
   region_name VARCHAR2(25),
   constraint regions_pk primary key (region_id)
   );
```

> a) Oracle creates new index on prmary key field, if no index exists on
>   the primary key field or its combination

While creating the table there will not be any index. First it will create the table, then index and primary key using that index.

> b) Oracle uses one of the index on prmary key field, if any index
>   exists on the primary key field or its combination but index is not
>   specified

If you already have the table and multiple indexes on the primary key column and want to create a primary key, you need to specify `using` clause and pass the index you want to use. If there is only one index then it will use that one index automatically.

> c) Oracle uses the index, if any index exists on the primary key field
>   or its combination and index name is specified

That is right. In case of multiple indexes you can specify using `USING` clause.